# CSS - 100% Height with Header and Footer

Tags: css

I am trying to design a page with a header, a main div that stretches to 100% of the vertical landscape (minus header and footer) and a footer. Like this pic:

[image]

I can get the header and main div to work. Like this:

```
    <div id="wrapper">

        <div class="header_div">HEADER</div>
        <div class="main_div">MAIN</div>
        <div class="footer_div">FOOTER</div>

    </div>
```

With this CSS:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
 }

 body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
 }

.header_div{

    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;

}

.main_div{

    margin-bottom:40px;
    margin-top:40px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    background-color: red;
}


.footer_div{

    position: relative;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

So the main div starts 40px off the top to account for the header and then stops 40px from the bottom to account for the footer. This works well but I cannot get the footer div to show below the main div. The way it is now with `position: relative` it's putting the footer on top of the main div. If I use `position:absolute` it puts it underneath the main div.

I am sure I am just doing this wrong because CSS is not my thing.

Any help on this would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason why you have an absolute position on .main_div?  That will be the what's causing the bad positioning of your footer.  If instead you have "position:relative", then the footer should show up below. -- edit -- Oh I see.  Never mind.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Using CSS3 **Flexbox**:

```css
/*QuickReset*/ * { margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

body {  /* or any parent wrapper */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100dvh;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>HEADER</header>
<main>MAIN</main>
<footer>FOOTER</footer>
```

Comment: This works really well with fixed header and footer height. Is it possible with dynamic footer and header ?

Comment: Your #content doesn't stretch to 100% of the vertical landscape. I have added red background for it. http://jsbin.com/sidokupofe/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Oh, sorry. I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 4):

## Use the css calc() function.

With this method, you don't have to define the position of the elements

#### Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dLmceybe/)

html:

```
<header>Header</header>
<main>Main</main>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

css:

```
html, body { 
    height: 100%
}

body {
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

header { 
    background-color: #000;
    height: 100px;    
}

main { 
    background-color: #AAA;
    height: calc(100% - 150px);    
}

footer { 
    background-color: #000;
    height: 50px;    
}
```

Comment: PS (will not work in IE8). Though position is not an extreme issue here. Is that it's pretty hard (if not by using JS) to make the footer height dynamic respective to it's **content size**. Another minus is that you have to **account for both Header and Footer heights** inside the `calc`. :(

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple method. Try this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PejHr/

HTML:

```
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="main">
    <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    padding: 50px 0px
}
#inner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #f0f;
}

#top, #bottom {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #333;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

#bottom {
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Your example not working now. Footer displayed on top and header under the `#main`.